# Не получается вернуть массив из функции

Tags: c

double * tabl_func(func, xmin, xmax, dx) – для заданного шага (dx) и интервала (xmin, xmax) возвращает
одномерный массив вычисленных значений, где func - указатель на выбранную функцию Y(x) или V(x) или S(x).
Я создал такую функцию

```
double* tabl_func(function f, double xmin, double xmax, double  dx){

    int i = 0;
    double sizemas;
    sizemas = ((xmax - xmin) / dx) + 1;
    double *arry = (double*)calloc(sizemas, sizeof(double));
    for (i=0;i<sizemas;i++)
    {
        xmin += dx;
        arry[i] = f(xmin);
    }
    return arry;
}
```

В main

```
double* arry;
arry = (double*)calloc(sizemas, sizeof(double));
arry=tabl_func(Y, a, b, z);
```

функия печати

```
void print_res(int size, double* arrx, double* arry)//функция печати
{
    printf(" x| f(x)|\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("--------------------\n");
        printf("| %5.5lf | %5.5lf |\n", arrx[i], arry[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Однако при печати выводится мусор, прошу помочь

Comment: Ну, начнем с того, что вы старательно устроили утечку памяти... Но покажите вывод на печать и саму функцию - потому что вывода мусора на первый взгляд не видно. Так сказать, приведите [самодостаточный и воспроизводимый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)...

Comment: Вот функция печати
void print_res(int size, double* arrx, double* arry)//функция печати
{
 printf(" x| f(x)|\n");
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {
  printf("--------------------\n");
  printf("| %5.5lf | %5.5lf |\n", arrx[i], arry[i]);
 }
 printf("\n");
}

Comment: arrx создаю в мейн , и он печатается правильно.

Comment: если использовать функцию print_res внутри функции tabl_func , печать проходит успешно

Comment: https://ideone.com/8dPyTi - что здесь не так, как у вас? Кстати, `sizemas` должен быть целочисленным, да и размер массива вы не возвращаете... И считать начинаете не с `xmin`, а с `xmin+dx`...

Comment: не понимаю в чём проблема, сделал , всё как Вы изменили, но опять выводится мусор опять

Comment: Дайте **полный** код - ну хоть выложите на файлообменник. Так это все - разговоры впустую..

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/7k1ns

Comment: Теперь еще скажите последовательность действий, которая приводит к ошибке :)

Comment: Он у вас не компилируется! Например, как скомпилировать такое - `pow(sin(pow(pow(x, 2) + 1, 2) - 1, 2), 3)`?

Comment: Всё компилируется, если написать просто , например printf("%lf",Y(5.0)) значение выводит

Comment: У вас `sin` берется от двух переменных, сами посмотрите...

Comment: даже если не брать в расчёт эту функцию, не выводит и на простой функции Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственное место, где у вас есть вывод -

```
    size = ((b - a) / z) + 1;
    arrx = (double*)calloc(size, sizeof(double));
    for (i = 0;i < size;i++, a += z)
    {
        arrx[i] = a;
    }

    switch (ant)
    {
    case 1:
        arry=tabl_func(Y, a, b, z);
        print_res(size, arrx, arry);
        break;
```

И что вы делаете? Считываете `a` и `b`, а потом старательно увеличиваете `a`, пока он не становится больше `b`. И передаете в функцию. У вас в фукции вычисления ничего не вычисляется, просто потому что `xmin > xmax`...

Comment: в каком месте у меня xmin становится больше xmax, все функции вычисляют, проблема с созданием массива в теле функции и непосредственной обработкой его в main

Comment: Ну добавьте в функцию `tabl_func` отладочный вывод - или в отладчике пройдитесь - и посмотрите, чему у вас равны аргументы при ее вызове.